# C# SoundPlayer macOS?

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, audio, playsound

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to use the the class SoundPlayer in a C# project on Visual Studio for Mac where I want to play a sine wave but this message occurred when I typed in "SoundPlayer":

> The type name 'SoundPlayer' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Media'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Windows.Extensions, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you think that maybe `Consider adding a reference to that assembly` already counts as a suggestion? Did you try it?

Comment: The documentation can be handy.  Take a look at the docs for System.Media.SoundPlayer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer.  Right up at the top: _Assembly:
System.Windows.Extensions.dll_.  It matches up with _Consider adding a reference..._

Comment: Thanks @Flydog57 for your kind reply. I have read the docs but I still cannot understand how it works. Probably my knowledges of Visual Studio and C# are still to weak. Thanks anyway

Comment: Right-click the project in the Solution Explorer.  Choose _Add_ then _Reference_.  In the dialog box that pops up, click on "Assemblies".  Find _System.Windows.Extensions_.  Click on it.  A check box appears next to it.  Click the check box, click OK

Comment: SoundPlayer is only available on Windows. That's why it's called "System.WINDOWS.Extensions" :-) You could try NAudio but it is quite big for simple tasks.

Comment: Thank you @AudioGuy sometimes the answers are right in front of us... I'll take a look at NAudio!